# Why is my function modifying the input variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hi I have a function that rotates a matrix, however I can't figure out why it works.

```
def rotate(matrix):
        matrix[:] = [[row[i] for row in matrix[::-1]] for i in range(len(matrix))]
```

I understand "[:]" creates a copy of the original matrix, but why is the original matrix getting rotated as well?

If I want to return a new rotated matrix without modifying the input, what can I do?

Thank you!!!

Comment: why to not create variable with different name instead of searching "hack"?

Comment: This was a question from leetcode and they said they want me to modify the original code. I came up with the answer but I don't know why it works, so I would like to know what's happening when I do "matrix[:]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `array[:] = [...]` overrides the values inside the array. The easiest solution would be to return the result directly and store the return value of the function inside a new variable.

```
def rotate(matrix):
    return [[row[i] for row in matrix[::-1]] for i in range(len(matrix))]

rot_matrix = rotate(matrix)
```

Comment: perfect that was exactly what I was wondering. One more question, why wouldn't the code work if I remove "[:]" and have only "matrix = "?

Comment: @dzhu Because then you would override the value `matrix` inside the function, but that would have no effect on anything outside the function. Maybe reading about the python namespace (variable scope) would be helpful for you (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/namespace#scope)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, slicing returns a copy of the (list) object.[image: Python Docs for list iterable]

And clearly you didn't assign the returned copy to another variable. You are just assigning the rotated matrix back to the main variable `matrix`.

The above screenshot is taken from the docs -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html